# Django. How to show in form ManyToMany field as a Select (dropdown list)

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have a **ManyToMany** relation **User->User_Towns->Towns**...

```
towns = models.ManyToManyField("Town", blank=False,verbose_name='Town',related_name="user_set", related_query_name="user")
```

...and in `SignForm` a want to show a `DropDownList` instead `MultipleChoice`. If in a form.py I write some like:

```
  fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_name','towns', 'phone',)
    widgets = {
        'towns': forms.Select(),
    }
```

I get a DropDownList but if I choose a town and submit the form it returns me an error:

```
[Enter a list of values]
```

Can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can put this method in the form.py:

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
   ...
   def clean_towns(self):
      return [self.cleaned_data['towns']]
```